# Difference between D3.js vs D3.min.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is the difference between D3.js and D3.min.js files? It seems enough to include only D3.min.js. What is D3.js for then?

Even http://d3js.org/ page suggests to get d3.min.js from internet and include into the body

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

When I extract downloaded zip from http://d3js.org/ i get both d3.js and d3.min.js

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `D3.min.js` file is the compressed version of the code. Which means it's smaller and suitable for production - faster loading.

The uncompressed version of the file `D3.js` is the version you would use in development stage of your app. You can browse the code easier & most of the IDEs have the "go to the function definition" functionality which is almost impossible if you use the compressed version of the file.

Both files have the same functionality.

This applies to other `javascript` libraries out there in the Internet.

Answer (score 7):

- **D3.js**     -> Human readable (for dev environment)
- **D3.min.js** -> Smaller size, faster loading (for production environment)

Answer (score 6):

As touched on by Ivanka, the non min version is better while developing as it allows for easier debugging when you get code errors.

For production, the min version allows for faster load times (I.e it is a smaller js file for the end user to download).

Answer (score 3):

"min" means mini-fied (compressed as mentioned making it light-weight and hence faster). Although we use the term compression, minification is different in the sense that it does not require to be uncompressed. It is a reduced version of the original javascript (by removing whitespace, newline chars, comments etc.) and can be read by the browser.

Any js library that you wish to include, it is best to mini-fy it and use while deploying. For large applications with many js libraries, external as well as their own, minification helps reduce page-load time significantly.

You can not only minify d3.js but any other js file, css or html. css is another example where mini-fication is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that in **d3.min.js** all the white spaces are removed. This is necessary because when you deploy your file, it has less to load with this file.

While d3.js can be used during development. It is easy to read and infact, you can make changes to this file so that it works with your needs. It is recommended to add the changes in a different file.

**There is no difference in the functionality of each.**

Answer (score 0):

### D3.min.js-

(1) It is minified version which is easily understood and read by 
     browser.
(2) Minified version removes whitespaces, any space and comments etc

### D3.js

(1) It is easy to read by users as it contains whitespaces, comments for easy understanding of users.

For faster loading of any js files, it is customary to use "min.js" ie minified version.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Minification isn't compression in the classic sense. Compressed code would have to be uncompressed first before execution.but here mininfied js will work directly without any uncompress.
in the d3.min.js it removes and optimize nonessential characters like comments and white space so that the code is still valid but as compact as possible. It's effectively a form of code obfuscation.
As such, it is not recommended for development because it makes the code much less readable and much harder to edit.
Minification happens anyway as part of the compilation process in most languages. By pre-minifying the files, you simply speed up the download and parsing process by a certain amount.