# Why does using D3.min version breaks this code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This simple code shows a scale and an axis object in console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script>    
      console.log(d3.scaleTime());
      console.log(d3.axisRight());
  </script>
</body>
```

However if I change the reference to `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>`, I get two `f l(n)...` outputs.  I thought there would be no difference between the two version, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711060/difference-between-d3-js-vs-d3-min-js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It logs the minified versions of both functions, no difference in functionality, minified versions is just not as readable as the regular version is.